# First appearance of going to past (time-travel) to change the present

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history, time-travel

There have been quite a few movies where people go back in time to change the past so that the present is altered. On top of my head are Back to the future (2), Men in Black (2), one of the recent X-Men movies where Logan goes back, one netflix movie I'm unable to get the name of  and if I think hard, I'm sure to come up with at least half a dozen movies or more which showed that to great effect.

While Stephen Hawking has dissed the idea of making a time-machine which can go to the past from the time a time-machine is invented (pity) does anybody know the first movie which used the trope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1933 film [Berkeley Square](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023794/?ref_=nv_sr_2) has the protagonist wanting to go back to experience sea faring England, and not change it, but he does.

The 1947 film [Repeat Performance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0039761/) has a woman wish she could go back in time and not repeat the mistakes that lead her to kill her husband. This uses magic instead of technology, but the effect is still the same. Time travel to change the past.